# How to generate link for developed Shiny app (RShiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I have developed a shiny app. I have to generate a link for my developed app such that if that link is clicked the corresponding application opens.

In addition to it, for instance, consider the link is stored in SpreadSheet. The spreadsheet contains details such as Email Id, Name and Link to the application. When the link is clicked, the corresponding Email Id should be displayed in the textBox in developed app.

I have no idea about this. Is it possible with R? Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: First for the link, aren't you going to deploy it somewhere? If so the location where you deploy it would become the link!

Comment: For second, you can try to send the email id as a URL paramater to the link and then capture that paramater information in the app.

Comment: I am not clear with link generation. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Like this http://projects.rajivshah.com/shiny/tensorflow/ depending upon the server or location where you deploy your shiny app, you'd get a link

Comment: Please post some code attempt Nevedha. We can assist you better that way